# Selenium: How to work with already opened web application in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking for a solution that could help me out automating the already opened application in `Chrome` web browser using `Selenium` and `Python` web driver. The issue is that the application is super secured, and if it is opened in incognito mode as `Selenium` tries to do, it sends special `code` on my phone. This defeats the whole purpose. Can someone provide a hacky way or any other work around/open source tool to automate the application.

Comment: Check if the OTP that you get is getting saved in database. If it is saving in database you can query database and proceed ahead.

Comment: Remote chances of getting the access to database, even if is being saved. Not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't start Chrome in incognito mode, It just creates a new and fresh profile in the temp folder. You could force Selenium to use the default profile or  you could launch Chrome with the debug port opened and the let Selenium connect to it. There is also a third way which is to preinstall the webdriver extension in Chrome. These are the only ways I've encountered to automate Chrome with Selenium.